# Crestron Deserialize in C# and send array to Simpl+

Tags: c#

Trying best how to take the following classes and deserialize a Json file to return each class values back to Simpl+.  I am able to receive the Total value but anything in a list I am at a lost.

```
public class Client
{
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string auxiliaryId { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string typeDescription { get; set; }
    public Hardware hardware { get; set; }
    public Network network { get; set; }
}

public class Hardware
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string softwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    public string hardwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}

public class Network
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string mac { get; set; }
    public object homepage { get; set; }
    public string dhcpSubnet { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please add more details? Are you using any library to parse your JSON file? And can you provide some C# sample code?
Thank you! I'll get back to you once that is done :)

Comment: Using Crestron.SimplSharp.SDK.Library v2.18.85

Comment: Using Crestron.SimplSharp.SDK.Library v2.18.85 

var json = File.ReadToEnd("/NVRAM/myJson/TriplePlayServerJson.json", Encoding.UTF8);
                var filecontents = new StringReader(json);
                var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(filecontents);
                var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                rootObject = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonTextReader);

Comment: public class RootObject
    {
        public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result TriplePlayResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {       
        [JsonProperty("clients")]
        public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
    }
    public class Client
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Locale { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure that you want to use Crestron? A library such as Newtonsoft would do perfectly the job and is even easier!
It includes a bunch of features

EDIT: Please include this code in your original question

Comment: This is Crestron Simpl# that is returning a value back to Simpl+ module. I am certain I have to use the Crestron Library otherwise not able to get any parsed data back to Simpl+.

Comment: If I can just use Newtonsoft I would but I have to include the Crestron library otherwise I won't receive the proper .clz file that Simpl+ requires to work with C#.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you shared in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following to the `foreach` statement:

```
args.MyIndex = (ushort)(rootObject.TriplePlayResult.clients.IndexOf(item) + 1);
```